# SparkContext' object has no attribute 'prallelize

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

Hi I am trying to run my first pyspark code in jupyter notebook. I got the issue as SparkContext' object has no attribute 'prallelize. Could you please help me out?

The codes are as shown below:

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
findspark.find()
import pyspark
findspark.find()
```

gives me the result as: C:\Users\Owner\spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7'--

```
from pyspark import SparkContext,SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
conf = pyspark.SparkConf().setAppName('SparkApp').setMaster('local')
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)
spark = SparkSession(sc)


myRDD = sc.prallelize([('Ross',19),('Joey',18),('Rachel',16),('Pheobe',18),('Chandler',17),('Monica',20),('Ram',25),('Hari',10)])
```

The above code gave me error as shown below:
AttributeError: 'SparkContext' object has no attribute 'prallelize'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
 from pyspark.sql import SparkSession 

 spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").getOrCreate() 
 sc = spark.sparkContext
 rdd_names = sc.parallelize([(1, "Joe"), (2, "Thomas"), (3, "Michael"), (4, "Sean")])
```

Comment: Now the code is working as expected. Thank You. I am not  able to figure out exactly what was the problem. Could you let me know what the problem  was exactly. Also since I am learning pyspark myself and this is my first code. Could you please suggest me some good resources to lean Pyspark either youtube videos or some resources online?

Comment: It seems you using some deprecated Sparksession initialization (Use Builder Method which is also documented here https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=sparksession ). In Addition to the offical Pyspark documentation you can have a look on Databricks, they have a lot of tutorials for pyspark (https://docs.databricks.com/languages/python.html) or have  a look at this Spark cheatsheet: https://www.datacamp.com/community/blog/pyspark-cheat-sheet-python.

Comment: :sure will do that. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Its a type error, it should be

```
myRDD = sc.parallelize([('Ross',19),('Joey',18),('Rachel',16),('Pheobe',18),('Chandler',17),('Monica',20),('Ram',25),('Hari',10)])
```

Comment: I could find the exact diffrence between my RDD sytanx and yours. Could you please let me what is the exact issue or where is the issue?

Comment: Its wrongly typed as `sc.prallelize()` in your posted code, wherein the correct intended method is `sc.parallelize`, you may also refer the [Spark API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#parallelize-scala.collection.Seq-int-scala.reflect.ClassTag-)